# Changing port value configureApplicationServer attribute Worklight

Tags: oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using Worklight 6.0.0.1 with Oracle as Backend Database.

I have two DB servers, one is listening on port 1525 (standard port) while other is listening on 1526.

I am trying to deploy a war file through ant on my worklight server. I used the template configure-liberty-oracle.xml and it worked like a charm while connecting to the DB server listening on Port 1525.

However, when I am trying to deploy the WAR file with Oracle DB (port 1526), it is not able to connect. Apparently port 1525 is mentioned somewhere in Worklight under the attribute `configureApplicationServer`.

Does anybody has any idea where can I change the connection port for Oracle DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection port for an Oracle DBMS is specified in the `<oracle server=... database... .../>` element, as [documented](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_configure_appserver_reference.html). Just add `port="1526"` in there.

The configuration samples use the default port, 1521.

Comment: I added below line to the configuration sample xml file, but still it was trying to connect through 1521

  <property name="oracle.database.port" value="1526"/>

Can you explain a bit further?